# Why am I getting an AssertionError when assigning Arrays.asList() to var directly?

Tags: java, arrays, exception, type-inference, java-10

I'm trying to understand [local variable type inference](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286) in Java 10.

1. The code below works perfectly during compilation and runtime:

   ```
   List list1 = Arrays.asList(1L, 2.0F, "3");
   var list2 = list1;
   ```
2. However, this line throws a compilation error:

   ```
   var list3 = Arrays.asList(1L, 2.0F, "3");
   ```

   > `Error:java: java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected intersection type: java.lang.Object&java.io.Serializable&java.lang.Comparable<? extends java.lang.Object&java.io.Serializable&java.lang.Comparable<?>>`

I don't really understand why the 2nd case is wrong but not the 1st case. Because I expect the compiler would infer the type of `list1` and treat `list2` and `list3` the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont think that got your issue right because I tried both the statements and got executed correctly: 

jshell> List  list3 = Arrays.asList(1L, 2.0F, "3");
list3 ==> [1, 2.0, 3]

jshell> List list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2.0, "3");
list1 ==> [1, 2.0, 3]

Comment: @AmanChhabra it's probably IntelliJ...

Comment: @Eugene No, I tried it on JShell and it worked fine

Comment: @AmanChhabra my point was that the OP issue is related to IntelliJ

Comment: @AmanChhabra Note the OP's code is different from what you put in your comment: `var list3` vs `List list3`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice right...

Comment: In the first example you are using the [*raw type*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/2711488) `List`. Of course, the compiler will *not* infer the *raw type* `List` when you use `var`…

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a bug in Java 10 compiler: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8199910

It is only reproduced when `javac` is called with a `-g` flag.

Possible workarounds:

1. Do not use the `-g` flag

   - If you use IDEA: Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Compiler → Java Compiler → Uncheck "Generate Debugging Info"
2. Do not use `var` with intersection types (use explicit types):

   - `List<Object> list = Arrays.asList(1L, 2.0F, "3");`
   - `var list = Arrays.<Object> asList(1L, 2.0F, "3");`
3. Use Eclipse which has its own compiler

### UDPATE:

The bug was fixed in [JDK 10.0.2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/10-0-2-relnotes-4477557.html).

Comment: thank you. it works after I uncheck "Generate Debugging Info".

Answer (score 12):

This is a bug of openjdk, see [this](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8199910):

> Javac should skip non-denotable types in the LocalVariableTypeTable
>   attribute

Comment: I believe this will be fixed in JDK 10 too. It will be crazy if they do not backport such a critical bug.

Comment: Thank guys, I confirm that it works by using jshell with `java version "10" 2018-03-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10+46)`