# Local Variable Type Inference with Conditional (Ternary) Operator of Different Types

Tags: java, var, type-inference, java-10

```
var test = "Hello World!";
```

In Java 10+, the above snippet compiles, and `test` is inferred to be a `String` at compile-time.

However, we can use the conditional (ternary) operator to return different types, such as:

```
var test = new Random().nextBoolean() ? "Hello World!" : 123;
```

If we were to print `test.getClass()` at runtime, it would output either:

> - class java.lang.String
> - class java.lang.Integer

This makes sense, but what would the type of `test` be at compile-time? Would it be `Object`, or something else?

Comment: Possibly duplicate/related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49558895/why-am-i-getting-an-assertionerror-when-assigning-arrays-aslist-to-var-directl

Comment: @Naman I'd argue against it being a duplicate, mainly because my code compiles on Java 12, and even running their code (that they say doesn't compile) on Java 12 compiles just fine for me. My question was more about, what is the compile-time type of this variable and why? I can see how the two are related, though.

Comment: Well, one can certainly do so and that's one of the reasons why I didn't actually vote to close this. But currently, the question and its answer are neither complementing nor very clear. That said, I am still leaving this to the community further to vote accordingly. Related to the link, the answer reads that the bug was fixed in a later version of JDK10.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50022830/advantages-drawbacks-of-var-in-java-10/50022921#50022921) look at the last sample for example

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, Intellij tells me that the type of `test` is not `Object`, but rather this beast:

```
java.io.Serializable & Comparable<? extends java.io.Serializable & Comparable<?> & constant.Constable & constant.ConstantDesc> & constant.Constable & constant.ConstantDesc
```

The reason why this is the case is because the compiler infers the type of the variable to be the *closest* common superclasses between `String` and `Integer`, which are in-fact `Serializable`, `Comparable`, `Constable`, and `ConstantDesc` in Java 12.

There's an interesting article that elaborates on *impossible types*, which are what these types are known as (since they can only be inferred by the compiler): [Representing the Impractical and Impossible with JDK 10 “var”](https://benjiweber.co.uk/blog/2018/03/03/representing-the-impractical-and-impossible-with-jdk-10-var/)

If we were to return objects that are entirely unrelated, such as `Integer` and `ByteArrayOutputStream`, then we would see that Java would infer the compile-time type of `test` to be `Object`:

```
var test = new Random().nextBoolean() ? 123 : new ByteArrayOutputStream();
```

Comment: [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43987285/2711488) also discusses the possibility of having variables with a non-denotable type, also with pre-Java 10 constructs.

Comment: This is covered by the third bullet of [JLS 15.25.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.3). What you called the “closest common superclass” is referred to here as the *lub* or *least upper bound* of the two types. But you have the intuition correct.